# Visual Studio 2010 slow to debug, lots of ascx controls, loading symbols I don't need?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a webforms ASP.NET application with lots of user controls (*.ascx). When I start with debugging, it appears to reload symbols for each control, each of which takes a second or two; as a result the app takes about a minute and a half to start any time the code changes. (I can subsequently stop and start debugging very quickly as long as there are no code changes.)

In the output window, I have dozens of lines like these:

```
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Herb Caudill\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1f256061\12a5d99\App_Web_hcj5xynv.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Herb Caudill\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1f256061\12a5d99\App_Web_facettextboxfilter.ascx.b3b3f5d8.obkscoie.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Herb Caudill\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1f256061\12a5d99\App_Web_editgridcolumnchooser.ascx.b3b3f5d8.o1vmswte.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Herb Caudill\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1f256061\12a5d99\App_Web_editgridimporttools.ascx.b3b3f5d8.mslzoqjj.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Herb Caudill\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1f256061\12a5d99\App_Web_facetsearchpager.ascx.b3b3f5d8.b-mkmweb.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Herb Caudill\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1f256061\12a5d99\App_Web_photogallery.ascx.b3b3f5d8.0mzg-l3y.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WebDev.WebServer40.EXE' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Herb Caudill\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1f256061\12a5d99\App_Web_facetcheckboxfilter.ascx.b3b3f5d8.krw3yihh.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

Almost none of these controls have anything to do with the page I'm debugging. Is there any way to speed up the debug process by not loading all these symbols I don't need?

**Note:** There are many similar questions that are answered with "delete all breakpoints" and/or issues to do with loading Microsoft symbols over the network. Neither one of those is the issue here.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198742/visual-studio-2008-2010-asp-net-how-to-speed-up-the-delay-after-rebuilding-the/9199027#9199027

Comment: Aristos - Setting `<compilation batch="false" optimizeCompilations="true" ... >` did the trick. Not sure what the proper way to wrap this up is - should I close as duplicate, or should you post this as an answer so you get credited for it?

Comment: I do not know ether. Maybe because your question have been asked different to make an answer, and if other likes they can close it as duplicate's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first I think that your issue that load many dll is maybe because you do not have turn off the compiler batch, so on each change the visual studio make more than one page compile.

So I suggest to try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9199027/159270 and its worked.

So set the `optimizeCompilations` to true, and `batch` to false

```
<compilation batch="false" optimizeCompilations="true" ... >
```

For asp.net version 3.5 must use this patch in order to work with this optimize switch.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961884

Do not make the same thing on the online server.

Answer (score 0):

There is an accepted answer for this on the msdn forums - original link here

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vsdebug/thread/a76c4fbe-93de-4875-b111-43a472876271

The answer below is cut and paste from there for convenience.

In Visual Studio you may influence symbol load-behaviour through "Modules Window" (accessible, when during debugging in break-mode through 'Debug->Windows->Modules), setting "Automatic Symbol Load Settings" to "Always Load Manually".

How to: Use the Modules Window
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9.aspx

Also you may use  "Symbols Settings" dialog, where you can specify, which symbols to load automatically
How to: Specify Symbol Locations and Loading Behavior
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx

Symbols, Debugging, Options Dialog Box
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b13s79c0.aspx

Comment: I already had it set to load everything manually, so this didn't help.