# ASP Project on Visual Studio bad performance while debuging

Tags: asp.net, performance, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a ASP Project running Visual Studio 2013 having very bad Performance while debuging/running the Project. The same Project running on a normal IIS Server is super fast with no Problems. Other Projects are running also super fast with no Problems (also on VS2013).

I have already tryed the following:

- Delete All Breakpoints does nothing.
- Debug or Release version, doesn't matter.
- start without Debugging has the same problem.
- Putting my project on a full IIS implementation on a web server runs it super fast with no problems.
- Clean Solution, or deleting the .suo also do nothing
- comment all the CodeBehind and the JavaScript
- the solution with symbol loading from [Visual Studio debugging/loading very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567984) also dont work.

Another often mentioned solution is to deactivate Intellitrace, but I don't found how to do that in VS2013 (the Intellitrace MenuItem in the Tools/Options Menu is missing)

There are many empty ScriptDocuments created while running, dont know if that has anything to do with the Problem.

Thanks for any Ideas!

Comment: Do you have disable the batch compile ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198742/visual-studio-2008-2010-asp-net-how-to-speed-up-the-delay-after-rebuilding-the/9199027#9199027

Comment: The issue is to debug it, or in general the page is slow ?

Comment: @Aristos yes i have also tryed disable the Batch compile.

Comment: @Aristos ah you're right in combination with turning debugmode off it works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Intellitrace will only be available if you are running Visual Studio Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound strange, I had the same problem and tried all suggestions I found  on the internet. The cause for me was I has a blank DVD in my drive. I found this by looking at where Visual Studio was trying to load the symbols from "my d drive (dvd)". After I ejected the blank DVD it was back to normal. This was very strange but just saying, check where VS is trying to load the symbols from in the output window. Hope this save someone from running round in circles.